# Make an object searchable with array_search in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search, interface, spl

I would like to make a class in PHP such as it would be searchable with PHP native method `array_search`. Currently my class implements `IteratorAggregate` and `Countable`, which allows me to do `foreach` on it.

There is a couple of other SPL interfaces (SeekableIterator, ArrayAccess, etc...) which seems to maybe fit, but I would like to know if someone has already done this and which interface is suitable for what I want to do.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Check out [FilterIterator](https://www.php.net/filteriterator). You implement your own class inheriting from it then do a compare in the `accept` method implementation in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Make your class extend `ArrayObject`, if possible. If that's not possible, try implementing each of the interfaces that ArrayObject implements, one-by-one based on [this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) to see which interface you really need to use for your object.

Comment: Or use the ArrayAccess interface to maintain type integrity.